# Node cannot find module "fs" when using webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using node.js and webpack to create a bundle. From what I've read, node.js should contain `fs` module for managing files. However when I call `require("fs")` I get an `Cannot find module "fs"` error. What should I do?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I came across this problem myself when bundling with webpack and found the answer on [this thread](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader/issues/8).

The way to solve it for me was to use the following config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          {  
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: 'node_modules',
              loader: 'babel',
              query: {presets: ['es2015']},
          }
      ]
  },
  target: 'node'
};
```

By setting target to node webpack will make the necessary changes to bundle your node application

Edit: This answer targeted webpack 1.x which has now been superseded.

Comment: Even though webpack is much newer, the `target: 'node'` line is still important and what makes this work on webpack v4

Comment: yeah agree, just having `target: 'node'` works, moreover, with webpack v5.88.2 the loaders strucutre has changed refer: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/.

Comment: Just check the NODE version, maybe some package requires a newer one

Answer (score 46):

If you are running your webpack bundle in nodejs environment then target: 'node' is required in webpack.config.js file otherwise webpack takes default value as web for target [check here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/).

You can resolve the issue in two ways

Add below configuration to your webpack.config.js

```
node: {
    fs: "empty"
}
```

**OR**

Add below configuration to your package.json

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
}
```

Edit:

promising fix is

```
"browser": {
   "fs": false
}
```

Comment: I got this error after I added the fs. 
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
   object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Options object for node compatibility features.

Comment: @SuuSoJeat that is because the version of your webpack is newer from this answer, [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428818/6791254) instead

Comment: Adding node: { fs: "empty" } to webpack.config.js did not work but adding "browser": { "fs": false } to package.json did! Success!

Comment: package.json entry did the job. Thanks :)

Comment: I had problem with 'path' in some legacy code and I did the exact opposite thing. After removing the "browser": { "path": false} now the webpack injects the correct object!

Answer (score 24):

Add below configuration to your webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
  fallback: {
    fs: false
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me when updating to laravel-mix v6

Comment: @kia nasirzadeh I have a similar error with Laravel 8 that I can't solve. Could you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032168/how-can-i-solve-the-problem-with-module-os-and-fs-using-npm-in-laravel-8

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue when bundling a **NWjs application using webworkers** (which in turn had node enabled).

The solution I found was to include each native module I used in `externals` with the prefix `commonjs`  to the name of the module. For example:

```
    ...
    target: "webworker", // or 'node' or 'node-webkit'
    externals:{
        fs:    "commonjs fs",
        path:  "commonjs path"
    }
    ...
```

I've done the same for targets "webworker" and "node-webkit" in different projects to solve the same issue.

[webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) [nwjs](/questions/tagged/nwjs) [webworker](/questions/tagged/webworker) [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) [node](/questions/tagged/node)

Answer (score 10):

I needed to build a class that would use `fetch` if executed in a browser, or `fs` if executed in node. For other reasons, it was impractical to produce separate bundles, so I produced a single browser-targeted bundle.

The solution I used was to use `eval('require("fs")')` if the script was running in node.

```
const fs = eval('require("fs")')
```

Browser-safe (`fs` is `null` in the browser):

```
const fs = typeof window === 'object'
    ? null
    : eval('require("fs")')
```

Answer (score 8):

After trying everything I found on the internet (`target`, `externals`, `node` configs), the only solution that actually worked for me was replacing:

```
const filesystem = require("fs")
        or
import fs from "fs"
```

by the special webpack version

```
const fs = __non_webpack_require__("fs")
```

This generates a require function that is not parsed by webpack.

Comment: My Electron doesn't understand what `__non_webpack_require__` is..

Answer (score 3):

*In addition to the answer of [PDG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46246272/9078344)*

I'm used to this short copy/paste candy.

Using **path** and **fs** :

```
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'))
  .filter(x => ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1)
  .forEach(mod => { nodeModules[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`; });

// Before your webpack configuration

module.exports = {
...
}
```

Then inside your configuration file, include the **nodeModules** variable in the **externals**

```
...
externals: nodeModules,
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be more elegant to use pre-defined solution as:
Adding `target: 'node'` to webpack config file.

More info on: [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I am not a pro `node.js` developer, just an unfortunate guy who is on frontend try to use somebody else's code.

you may have wondered why error occurs, obviously, `node.js` provides more than frontend, many opensource thereby integrite modules such as `fs`, `path`, for building backend approaches.

**So how the heck can I ignore, you know the backend part of implementation, in order to get this work?**

---

##### Option 1

> nullify backend modules

add to `webpack.config.js`

```js
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        fs: false,
        path: false,
    },
},
```

also add corresponding to `package.json`, otherwise you are likely to get a `Filed 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`

```json
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
},
```

this will do if the dependency does not rely on the backend module, that means, not doing stuff like *writing local file during runtime*, and not accessing the `prototype` from any declared in that module.

---

##### Option 2

> browserify polyfill

polyfill are basically a piece of code that fill the functionality gap, `browserify` provides object that stimulate that dependency's interface, with that help, in minified code, for example, if `fs.readFile` is called, it won't throw a `undefined error`, but the function would return `null` and continue to run.

```js
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        fs: require.resolve("browserify-fs"),,
        path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),,
    },
},
```

you may notice the prefix `browserify-` and surfix `-browserify` are different, it's not a typo, depending on the module you actually need to search for a valid name on npm. here are some common names you can dirrectly use:

- browserify-fs
- browserify-zlib
- browserify-shim
- path-browserify
- stream-browserify
- crypto-browserify

here's a quick note, after plugin multiple polyfill, the `production` mode build may compile a file with enomous file size. you may wanna directly use `development` mode, though it writes tons of file.

Answer (score -2):

For the solution we are building we had to force an older version of webpack:

```
npm install --save --force webpack@webpack-3
```