# How to load Nodejs core modules using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, es6-module-loader

I'm having trouble loading the core modules of nodejs to the browser.

My `xlsx` library depends on `fs` which is a core module and loading my app produces `cannot find module "fs"` error.

I've done some googling repeatedly ended up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249237/node-cannot-find-module-fs-when-using-webpack) - saying I should add `target:node` to my `webpack.config.js` file BUT, done as he suggested produces another error -> `process is not defined`

I was wondering if there's any module-loader for that need? i couldnt find any.

**`webpack.config.js`**:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/boot",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts/,   loaders: ["ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ],
    preLoaders: [
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", exclude: ['node_modules', 'ext-*', 'lib', 'tools'] }
    ]
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Any insights would be much apreciated, thanks in advance and please let me know if any other information would be helpful.

*I'm not using `babel` nor `gulp`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

There is no equivalent to `fs` that would work properly in the browser. JavaScript executed in a browser is running in a sandbox for security reasons and you have only very limited access to the client's file system, [which is what the module `fs` is used for in NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense. so what am i supposed to do having the `xlsx` using `fs`?

Comment: That depends on the library. Can you use it without `fs` by e.g. loading the file manually via HTTP requests from your server? Then do that. Otherwise you'll have to look for a different library.

Comment: That probably is out of the scope of the question but more precisely I'm using `ng2-file-uploader` to get a file from the client and the using `node-xlsx` to parse the file to an object, all that on the client without using the server, any suggestions?

Comment: `node-xlsx` seems to have NodeJS's API baked into it and won't be of any help to you. It is based on `js-xlsx` though, which seems to be able to run in a browser as well: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx