# Uncaught TypeError: fs.exists is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, fs

I am having trouble with the fs module error in Node JS Application. I am using Webpack also,

My .js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../app/logs/logs.txt');

module.exports.displayInfo = (info, containerID = 'info-dock') => {
  fs.exists(filePath, (exists) => {
    if (exists) {
      console.log('Present');
    }
  });
  let message;
  if (info.message) {
    message = info.message;
  } else {
    message = 'No message supplied.';
  }

};
```

My webpack config file :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './clientSide/index.js',
  cache: true,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['env'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  target: 'web',
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  }
};
```

When I am trying to run and call displayInfo method in my application, on the browser's console, I get an error: ncaught TypeError: fs.exists is not a function.

Does anybody know how to correct this?

Comment: Did you already take a look at [this config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249237/node-cannot-find-module-fs-when-using-webpack)?

Comment: I have tried this, but the problem is in my project I am using process also,if I change to node then it gives the the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Comment: You can't use `fs.exists` in a web app/site running in a standard browser. Browsers run websites in a sandbox for security purposes, and the sandboxes don't allow much access to the filesystem of the user.

Comment: The real problem I am facing is using i18n-2 module. When I am trying to use i18n-2 module in this, because internally i18n-2 module uses fs and again then it is giving me same error.

Comment: @Akshay This module is build for usage with node js, and not for browsers.

Comment: Can you recommend anyth i18n module built for browsers?

Comment: @Akshay This is highly subjective, and does not fit the Q&A format of StackOverflow. Nevertheless, if you just google "webpack i18n" you should be able to find a couple.