# Cannot file './fs' module when creating Vue app with 'vue create hello-world'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, macos-mojave

I have been trying to use Vue for the past 3-4 hours now and it is feeling like an uphill battle to just get it set up.

I am following this documentation: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create

I have the following library versions on my computer

```
macOS Mojave 10.14.5
node -v v10.16.0
npm -v 6.9.0
vue --version 3.8.3
```

My problem is below.

```
$ vue create hello-world
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:6:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried Node version 10.15.3 because some people had luck with it here
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3879

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using Yarn or any other package manager? What options did you choose when running the command? Have you tried with different Node versions?

Comment: Based on https://npm.community/t/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js-605-throw-err-error-cannot-find-module-aproba/4786 you can try reinstalling the vue CLI and/or npm.

Comment: Hello @YangshunTay, I am not using Yarn. I have tried sudo and I get the same error. No I have not yet. I am working with someone tomorrow morning who has a MAC and plan to get his versions and try. I have also done a full reinstall of npm,  node and vue.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249237/node-cannot-find-module-fs-when-using-webpack

Comment: Hey@SatyamPathak I apologize if this is a duplicate. I will try it first thing tomorrow morning

Comment: Hello again @SatyamPathak. My friend helped me fix it this morning. I did not have to change my versions of npm, node or vue

Answer (score 0):

It was a pretty simple fix and it had nothing to do with the versions I was running. Assuming you have used `npm install -g @vue/cli` and are using a mac you should be able to do:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
```

Then for a fresh start do this again.

```
npm uninstall -g @vue/cli 
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Comment if it did not work and I will try my best to help you.