# How can I solve the problem with module 'os' and 'fs' using npm in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, npm, node-modules, laravel-mix

Suddenly I received the following error:

```
app.js:28823 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'os'
at webpackMissingModule (app.js:28823)
at Object../node_modules/laravel-mix/src/File.js (app.js:28823)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:79613)
at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:6700)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:79613)
at app.js:79751
at Function.__webpack_require__.O (app.js:79650)
at app.js:79753
at app.js:79755
```

I tried deleting the `node_module` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, and run `npm install`, to no avail.

When I launch `npm run dev` I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\...\node_modules\clean-css\lib\options'" -t "Laravel Mix"
```

**UPDATE:** I run `npm install --save os` and this problem was solved. But another one arose!  `Error: Can't resolve 'fs'` and this one doesn't resolve with `npm install --save fs`

NPM version: 7.18.1

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**: I don't know how in the top of `resources\js\app.js` file appeared this line:

```
const { exists } = require("laravel-mix/src/File");
```

I just deleted it and `npm run dev` didn't give any more errors.
I hope this answer will help someone else.

Comment: thanks today I face this exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

This all happens when you auto-import the modules using any extension.

Solution:
delete the package-lock.json file and run:
npm i

it works for me.

Another solution is to remove the
import { exists } from 'laravel-mix/src/File'
from the react component first line and it works.