# How to Read/Write Json files with webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm running an admin panel on localhost using webpack.

I'm trying to save a bunch of objects into a json file in the same directory using `fs` which doesn't work.

The error I receive: `Node cannot find module "fs"`

I understand that 'fs' belongs to NodeJS environement which webpack can't really use, so my question is whether there's another alternative to reading/writing json files with webpack.

Thanks!

Comment: does one of this answer your question: [Node cannot find module "fs" when using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249237/node-cannot-find-module-fs-when-using-webpack) or [Can't resolve 'fs' when bundle with webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447)

Comment: @MeerArtefakt None of those answers allow me to write/read to JSON files with webpack.