"ReferenceError: fs is not defined" with Webpack 4
Good morning everybody.
I'm trying to test the "parse-kml" package but I receive several errors when bundling the script.
I tried with Webpack v5, but I had some problems due to a lot of missing polyfilss, so I'm getting back to Webpack v4.
Here's some code
webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  externals: ["fs", "net", "tls"],
  mode: "development",
}

package.json
{
  "name": "kmltest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.47.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "parse-kml": "^1.0.1",
    "tls": "0.0.1"
  }
}

index.js
const parseKML = require("parse-kml");
// Read KML From File
parseKML
  .readKml("./test.kml")
  .then((res) => console.log("Loaded"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("error"));


index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="test content" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing KML/h1>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

As you can see, there's nothing so complicated, but once I bundle the script and open the webpage, my console shows this error:

It's my very first time I configure webpack on my own, so I'm sure I made some mistakes.
Could you help me?
Thank you!

You're trying to run a Node.js script in a browser, that's not going to work.

@Teemu I just need to bundle the script in order to use it in the browers for a specific project. Will "html-webpack-plugin" be helpful?

Something like fs just has no equivalent in the browser - the browser does not expose a filesystem. So whatever you pack with any system (from webpack to rollup) will not be able to actually include this kind of module since it just can't exist. It can't be packaged for web.

fs indeed belongs to nodejs itself

please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059255/5334486 they test typeof window === 'object' to understand if the app is running in a terminal or in a browser, and then use FS or FETCH accordingly

Here are some things you should know:

Client-Side Dependencies:

You cannot use require on the client side imported javascript file.
Include dependencies in the HTML file via CDNs if you have to.


Using fs in Node.js:

The fs module is built into Node.js and does not require any additional installation or configuration.
The line "fs": "0.0.1-security" in your package.json file is unnecessary and should be removed.


Managing Dependencies:

Any third-party library should automatically install all its dependencies.
Follow these steps to clean up and reinstall dependencies:

Delete the node_modules directory.
Remove the line "fs": "0.0.1-security" from your package.json file.
Run npm install or yarn install to reinstall the dependencies.




Running Your Node.js Script:

For a simple proof of concept, do not use Webpack or other bundlers.
Just install the necessary packages and run your script with node index.js.
HTML files are not needed for this setup.



The library is probably fine. Give it another try after you made the steps above. You can confgure webpack later when you need to.

Smells like teen spirit. No, sorry, smells like chatGPT

Thank you. Your solution is fine, and the script is working. The problem now is that I need to use my js script inside a WordPress plugin, so I need to embed it inside the php file, and not simply calling it in the console.

If this kml file is like a text file, you should be able to use the pareser via javascript in the browser.
